# Наследование в Room

Tags: java, room

Пытаюсь реализовать наследование.
есть 3 класса

родительский

```
    @Entity (tableName = "diaryday")
public class DiaryDay {

    @ColumnInfo (name = "diaryday_id")
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    long id;

    @ColumnInfo
    String description;

    @ColumnInfo
    Date created;
```

1й дочерний (2й аналогичный)

```
@Entity(tableName = "diarydaymental",
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = DiaryDay.class, parentColumns = "diaryday_id", childColumns = "diary_day_id"))

public class DiaryDayMental extends DiaryDay {
@ColumnInfo
@NonNull
@PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
long id;

@ColumnInfo
long resultDepr;

@ColumnInfo
long resultBurn;

@ColumnInfo
long diary_day_id;
```

при запуске программы выскакивает ошибка: Note: PrimaryKey[id] is overridden by PrimaryKey[id]
public class DiaryDayMental extends DiaryDay {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class DiaryDayMental extends DiaryDay {
/*
  @ColumnInfo
  @NonNull
  @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
  long id;
*/
...
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вы лучший! :)

Comment: @nameless Пожалуйста. Успехов.